# Converting Greek to Uppercase in Java

Tags: java, localization, internationalization

What I'm trying to do is fairly simple:

```
String example = "Τάχιστη αλώπηξ βαφής ψημένη γη - Mary Had A Little Lamb";
String upper = example.toUpperCase();
```

In Greek, only the first letter of an uppercase word should contain accented characters.

```
// upper contains the following (incorrect) string:
// ΤΆΧΙΣΤΗ ΑΛΏΠΗΞ ΒΑΦΉΣ ΨΗΜΈΝΗ ΓΗ - MARY HAD A LITTLE LAMB

// correct string:
// ΤΑΧΙΣΤΗ ΑΛΩΠΗΞ ΒΑΦΗΣ ΨΗΜΕΝΗ ΓΗ - MARY HAD A LITTLE LAMB
```

(The accents are hard to see, but they're there.)

According to the [Java 1.7 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28java.util.Locale%29), I should be able to pass a locale to `toUpperCase`, like so:

```
String upper = example.toUpperCase(new java.util.Locale("el"));
```

However, it looks like there are no specific rules for `toUpperCase` which handle Greek correctly.

Is it possible to define the behavior of `toUpperCase` for a particular locale, so that I can ensure I get the correct result?

Alternatively, I can just write a utility class to handle this particular case. But if it's possible, I'd prefer to override this function per locale, in case this comes up for other languages.

Comment: Looking at the source of `toUpperCase`, it appears that it just translates each character individually without looking at the rest of the text, except for three cases: Turkish, Azeri, Lithuanian.  Those are hard-wired into the code.  So you'll probably have to roll your own.  (P.S. Maybe you should submit this as a bug report to Oracle.)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I didn't see one, but I was hoping that there was a way to extend that behavior per locale.

Comment: P.S. The hard-wired code looks like `boolean localeDependent = (lang == "tr" || lang == "az" || lang == "lt");`.  _They're using `==` to compare strings._  Gaaaaaaaaack.

Comment: @Glen: Can you give me the link to the source of grammar rule related to upper-casing Greek characters? So far I know that Final Sigma is treated correctly while lower-casing, but I never heard about the rule you mentioned.

Comment: Probably the best example is the [`text-transform` specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform), which states the following:

    In Greek (el), vowels lose their accent when the whole word is in uppercase (ά/Α), except for the disjunctive eta (ή/Ή). Also, diphthongs with an accent on the first vowel lose the accent and gain a diaeresis on the second vowel (άι/ΑΪ).

See also: [Accent Marks denoting Stress in Greek, and Other Diacritics](http://www.foundalis.com/lan/grstress.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @ajb, this is not supported in Java by default. I had to create my own solution.

---

**Edit:** I solved this via `text-transform: uppercase` in front-end CSS, so not particularly relevant to the original question in Java. Turns out that was the simplest answer for this web-based application.

Comment: what solution??

Comment: @Meo as described above, this was handled in CSS.

Answer (score -1):

i tried the following and seemed to work:

```
String example = "Τάχιστη αλώπηξ βαφής ψημένη γη - Mary Had A Little Lamb";
String upper = example.toUpperCase();
String temp = Normalizer.normalize(upper, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(temp).replaceAll(""));
```